# difficulties with SQL code with string variable in it

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

So I have an Acces Database connected to my VBA login frm, which directs you to a sign up frm for a school holiday

I've got a particular weird problem in my vba code, because it can't continue with my sql part, whatever I dp. VBA thinks the result it get's from the SQL is not correct or negative.

I've put some SQL statements with a string in it;

because the loginID from the student who logs in on my program can only see specific locations for the holiday in a combobox, because the student is in a certain class, but other students from lower classes have to see their own locations, but some of those are combined for both classes.

Somehow my SQL code is not right;

In the Database table BEHEER there is a LoginID (leerlingnr in code) and a Password (wachtwoord) their class is called Klas. for the ease: one student has ID 12 and Password 1 In the table Leerlingen (students in Dutch) he is now assigned to class 1, but int the future he will be in A5A, but for safety of code crashes I made it 1.

```
Public Class frmInschrijven

Dim strSql As String = ""

Dim strConnectionString As String = ""

Private Sub frmInschrijven_Load() Handles MyBase.Load
'Declareer alle variabelen
Dim strUsername2 As String = ""
Dim strKlas As String = ""
'Bepaal CommandText (=SQL statement om records op te vragen:
strSql = "SELECT B.Leerlingnr, L.Leerlingnr, Wachtwoord, L.KLas, plaats FROM BEHEER B, LEERLINGEN L, Plaatsen P"

'Definieer de verbinding:
strConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=Werkweek.accdb"
'Maak connection aan op basis van de connectionstring en
'command op basis van de SQL opdracht en gemaakte connection:
Dim objConnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(strConnectionString)
Dim objCommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSql, objConnection)
'Open de verbinding:
objCommand.Connection.Open()
'Maak een DataReader aan op basis van de ingestelde command:
Dim objDataReader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = objCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
'Doorloop de Leerlingnr's om te zien in welke klas ze zitten

'Doorloop alle records in de tabel:
While objDataReader.Read
    strUsername2 = frmInloggen.strUsername
    'Nog zorgen dat ALLEEN data van 1 leerling beschikbaar is, dan pas kan strKlas

    strKlas = objDataReader("Select Klas FROM LEERLINGEN L, BEHEER B WHERE L.Leerlingnr=""" & frmInloggen.strUsername & """AND B.LEERLINGNR=L.LEERLINGNR")
    If strKlas = "1" Then
        MsgBox("Correct, you saved me!")

    ElseIf strKlas Like "H4A" Then
        With cboKeuze1
            .Items.Add("apart")
        End With


    Else MsgBox("try again")
    End If


End While
'Sluit de DataReader en de Connection:
objDataReader.Close()
objConnection.Close()
End Sub
```

BEHEER And LEERLINGEN both have student ID's, where in BEHEER it is used as an Username.

If you get the messagebox correct, you saved me then the code should work, but right now I'm unable to pass this part:

```
  strKlas = objDataReader("Select Klas FROM LEERLINGEN L, BEHEER B WHERE L.Leerlingnr=""" & frmInloggen.strUsername & """AND B.LEERLINGNR=L.LEERLINGNR")
```

Can someone please help me out.
If I have to include my entire .sln please request and I will offer it to you.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: VBA? You mean VB.NET. Side note: Never use concatenated strng as a query. Instead of it, use parameterized queries! See: [How to: Execute a Parameterized Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

As i mentioned in the comment to the question, you have to use parameterized query instead of concatenating string! That's the common reason of [SQL injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection).

A proper way of doing it is:

```
Dim command As New OleDbCommand()
command.CommandText = _
   "SELECT <ListOfColumns>" & vbCr _
    "FROM YourTable WHERE Column1 = @Parameter1"
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter1", rmInloggen.strUsername)
```

For further details, please see:
[OleDbCommand.Parameters Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)
[OleDbParameterCollection.AddWithValue Method (String, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Sorry I did not react to that, but I also did not understand that, I will try this and suggestions from others. Thank you very much

Comment: And how should I insert this into a combobox?

Comment: You can use for example a [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) object. `Dim oRdr As OleDbReader = command.ExecuteReader() Dim oDt As DataTable = New DataTable dt.Load(oRdr)` Now, use `Combobox1.DataSource = dt`

Comment: By the way, I still don't really know how to implement your code, I'm not that good at vba

Comment: It's not a VBA! It's a VB.NET!

Comment: What do I need to use in my if statement, where .... = "1" then........

Comment: Jay I guess the way he has presented things to you, need not you to be expert.

Answer (score 0):

Check the very last statement =

```
strKlas = objDataReader("Select Klas FROM LEERLINGEN L, BEHEER B WHERE L.Leerlingnr=""" & frmInloggen.strUsername & """AND B.LEERLINGNR=L.LEERLINGNR")
```

should be

```
    strKlas = objDataReader("Select Klas FROM LEERLINGEN L, BEHEER B WHERE L.Leerlingnr='" & frmInloggen.strUsername & "' AND B.LEERLINGNR='L.LEERLINGNR'")
```

Comment: Nothing has been changed to me. The only difference is that, taht OP uses doble quote and you're using single quote. This means the same.

Comment: I'm not a questioner.

Comment: Let him try it :)

Comment: Should I give you a Dropbox Link?

Comment: No. We can chat and I can help you in debugging. As you have mentioned that you are getting error `Select Klas FROM LEERLINGEN As L, BEHEER As B WHERE L.Leerlingnr='' AND B.LEERLINGNR=L.LEERLINGNR' That extra double quote is troubling you. You should be careful about the string concatenation.

Comment: I agree with @VishalKumarSahu - string concatenation for queries opens you up for SQL injection.

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu I know that there is such a danger, but this isn't for any public use, I'm doing a pretty big program for a school assignment, and I can use double quote or just ' " " ' , the thing is still the same, only thing that appears to trouble was the variable from the other form which had no value. Still great thanks for the suggestions and help.

Comment: @Fabulous
The upper comment was meant for you too.

Comment: @Jayseiwald is it possible there are `'` characters in the string you are concatenating? I recall from an early project, I would save certain comments and my code would break if someone entered a comment like "I can't complete this application". My immediate solution was to use something like `.." & comment.Replace("'"C, "''") & "..` (That was in VB6 so it used VB6 syntax but is essentially the same). It is this way though that I discovered query parameters and started using them instead.

Comment: @Fabulous
There is no way there will ever be '"' in the username or password, given that the school only uses numbers and letters. The only thing left is that the objDatareader doesn't give me a value. Maybe I have to convert it to a string, but I'm not quite sure how to do that in OleDb

Answer (score 0):

It should read - with a space:

```
strKlas = objDataReader("Select Klas FROM LEERLINGEN As L, BEHEER As B WHERE L.Leerlingnr='" & frmInloggen.strUsername & "' AND B.LEERLINGNR=L.LEERLINGNR")
```

Comment: Sorry, this is what I got back, but i haven't tried out @Maciej his solution, because I don't quite understand it.  Got this : An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Select Klas FROM LEERLINGEN As L, BEHEER As B WHERE L.Leerlingnr='' AND B.LEERLINGNR=L.LEERLINGNR

Comment: If you get `Select Klas FROM LEERLINGEN As L, BEHEER As B WHERE L.Leerlingnr='' AND B.LEERLINGNR=L.LEERLINGNR` then `frmInloggen.strUsername` is empty.

Comment: @Gustav Yes after a moment of thinking I came to that conclusion, but how can I make a variable from another form to keep its value until the entire program stops

Comment: Create a public variable or a property of class _frmInschrijven_ named, say, `LaatsteLeerlingnr`. Set this before closing the form. Adjust SQL to: `.. WHERE L.Leerlingnr='" & LaatsteLeerlingnr & "' AND ..` .

Comment: Well I've done it by converting the string from the login form to a label in the other form, then I took the lbl.text as the variable, but I concluded that the datareader does not give a value. Should I make the datareader like this? objDatareader.getstring("_SQL Code_")

Comment: @Gustav I forgot to tag you above

Comment: I can't tell. I use _DataTableAdapter_, not the OleDb stuff. However, there should be many many examples out there for the browsing.

Comment: @Gustav I am unable to find anything, but I don't have time to rewrite everything. Problem is that the datareader gives me nothing, I don't know how to convert it into a string.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not familiar with the OldDbDataReader  ... it was the SQL that caught my eye.